# How to get rid of inactive nodes in Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, quorum, quorum-maker

I am setting up a quorum network with Quorum-maker, which uses Geth. 
It is running at the moment, with three alive nodes. However, earlier I had attempted to create two other nodes, which failed. I have since killed them off.

Now, the master node is still trying to connect to them multiple times per second. This creates a lot of logs. These logs are in the gethLogs directory, which is why I believe this is a geth issue rather than quorum specific.

```
INFO [06-20|04:45:34.146] peer is currently unreachable peer id=4
2019-06-20 04:45:34.146757 I | rafthttp: peer 5 became active
2019-06-20 04:45:34.170051 E | rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
2019-06-20 04:45:34.170210 E | rafthttp: failed to dial 5 on stream MsgApp v2 (peer 5 failed to find local node 1)
2019-06-20 04:45:34.170227 I | rafthttp: peer 5 became inactive
2019-06-20 04:45:34.170770 E | rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
INFO [06-20|04:45:34.246] peer is currently unreachable            peer id=4
2019-06-20 04:45:34.246934 I | rafthttp: peer 5 became active
2019-06-20 04:45:34.270846 E | rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
2019-06-20 04:45:34.271017 E | rafthttp: failed to dial 5 on stream MsgApp v2 (peer 5 failed to find local node 1)
2019-06-20 04:45:34.271034 I | rafthttp: peer 5 became inactive
2019-06-20 04:45:34.271437 E | rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
INFO [06-20|04:45:34.346] peer is currently unreachable            peer id=4
2019-06-20 04:45:34.347058 I | rafthttp: peer 5 became active
2019-06-20 04:45:34.371589 E | rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
2019-06-20 04:45:34.371746 E | rafthttp: failed to dial 5 on stream MsgApp v2 (peer 5 failed to find local node 1)
2019-06-20 04:45:34.371763 I | rafthttp: peer 5 became inactive
2019-06-20 04:45:34.372624 E | rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
INFO [06-20|04:45:34.446] peer is currently unreachable            peer id=4
2019-06-20 04:45:34.447434 I | rafthttp: peer 5 became active
2019-06-20 04:45:34.472487 E | rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
2019-06-20 04:45:34.472664 E | rafthttp: failed to dial 5 on stream MsgApp v2 (peer 5 failed to find local node 1)
2019-06-20 04:45:34.472680 I | rafthttp: peer 5 became inactive
2019-06-20 04:45:34.473471 E | rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000
```

The message itself makes perfect sense, these two nodes (4 & 5) don't exist anymore, hence it makes sense that geth can't connect. What I am looking for is a way to get Geth to stop trying to connect to these nodes. Ideally I want to delete them from the master node entirely. At the very least I want geth to stop logging about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the stale nodes from Raft.

Instructions on how to do this can be found in the [Quorum docs](http://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Consensus/raft/#initial-configuration-and-enacting-membership-changes).

Comment: Hm, it says "attach to a JS console and issue raft.removePeer(raftId)", but doesn't explain what that means. How do I get this JS console with raft?

Comment: You need to attach to the geth JS console to issue commands like raft.removePeer. That's done using `geth attach`, but you'll need a further parameter to specify the http address or the IPC file.
Take a look in the Ethereum docs if you need further info on that - it's standard Ethereum.

Comment: geth console is a wrapper around JSON-RPC methods geth node exposes via the `rpcapi`, `wsapi`, or ipc. You may also curl the API directly or use our JS library that offers raft API in the extensions: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum.js/

Comment: @Satpal Sandhu: I'm afraid that still doesn't help. How do I get a "JS console"? geth attach just gets me the normal go terminal and raft doesn't work there.

Comment: @fixanoid quorum-js seems to be broken, complains "TypeError: web3.extend is not a function"

Comment: oh, that actually is the Javascript console, says so on the top. Weird, why would a Go tool have a JS console? Anyway, it still doesn't work, when I type raft, it just says  "ReferenceError: 'raft' is not defined"

Comment: The 'ReferenceError: 'raft' error means that you haven't enabled the raft API.
On your geth command line you will have an `--rpcapi` parameter, this needs `raft` added to it. e.g. `--rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft`

This will enable the raft API.

Comment: @MaxBinnewies quorum.js needs a particular version of web3: esnure your dependency in package.json is "web3": "1.0.0-beta.36" like here: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum.js/blob/master/package.json#L53

Comment: I finally got quorum-js to work and was able to run raft.removePeer(), updating nodeJS finally fixed it. However, it doesn't work. I've experimented with it all day and it seems like it only works for nodes that are still running... I have created a GitHub issue with quorum directly as it seems there is currently no way to remove dead nodes from a cluster: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/753 Thanks for all your help, guys!